# How to update values in more than one column based on another column with M in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a table with quite a few numeric columns that I need to update multiplying their values by another column.
For example, if the original table were like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | Multiplier |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|     100 |      50 |      30 | 2          |
|     100 |      50 |      30 | 0.5        |
|     100 |      50 |      30 | 1          |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

I'd need to update it like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | Multiplier |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|     200 |     100 |      60 | 2          |
|      50 |      25 |      15 | 0.5        |
|     100 |      50 |      30 | 1          |
+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

[This post](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/07/23/transforming-a-column-with-values-from-another-column-in-powerbi-and-powerquery-in-excel/) explains how to do it one column at a time, and in my case this approach looks like this:

```
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns", each [value 1], each [value 1] * [Multiplier], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"value 1"}),
#"Replaced Value 2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value", each [value 2], each [value 2] * [Multiplier], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"value 2"}),
#"Replaced Value 3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value 2", each [value 3], each [value 3] * [Multiplier], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"value 3"})
```

Is there a way to do this, or something similar, in one single step?

Comment: You'll probably want [`Table.TransformColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-transformcolumns). Give that a try and let us know if you have any specific problems. It's always a good idea to take a look at the [Power Query/M function reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference) for this sort of thing - language references exist for a reason, and Stack Overflow is not meant to replace them.

Comment: Thank you @greggyb, I'll try that

Comment: Thank you @AlexisOlson, you are right, this worked

Comment: Following the solution in @AlexisOlson suggested post, my step now looks like this: #"Transform" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows( #"Renamed Columns",
        each [
            #"value 1" = [value 1] * [Multiplier],
            #"value 2" = [value 2] * [Multiplier],
            #"value 3" = [value 3] * [Multiplier],
            #"Multiplier" = [Multiplier]
                    ]))